# SvelteKit Navigation goto State

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In SvelteKit navigation [goto](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-navigation) allows to pass `state` in the second argument such as:

```
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

// ...

goto('/login', { state: { foo: 'bar' } });
```

The documents do not make it clear how `state` can be consumed/retrieved after the resulting navigation has occurred. `state` does not seem to be present on [$page](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores) nor seems to be available on `$navigating`.

How do you consume `state` passed to second argument of `goto()`? Is it currently missing and you have to create your own writable store to manage this state?

This is an [adapter-static](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static) SvelteKit application.

Answer (score 5):

The state being referred to is the one held on the [history stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state) of your browser tab or window.

You can access it in two different ways:

- directly by reading the value of `history.state`, although not very useful in practice as it returns the value of the state *at the top of the history stack* only
- by listening to [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) events, which will fire when the history stack is 'popped' (ex.: hitting back button on your browser or navigating programatically), in which case the `state` will be a property on the synthetic `event` object passed to the listener when the event fires

Comment: You are indicating that sveltekit has no built in way such a store to interact with that state added to history? Or are you saying there is a store for history available via kit? A bit unfortunate as something like react-router-dom that has the same exact mechanism for passing state on navigation, provides the ability to access that state in its equivalent of `$page`

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no specific mechanism in place in Svelte to handle History's state, as it is a mechanism that is not particular to Svelte. Afaik, `react-router-dom` relies on the `history` npm package, where Svelte interacts with the standard History API provided by your browser, so they're a bit different.

Comment: You can still add a listener for the `popstate` event without too much complexity, however, locating it in your top-most container (e.g. your root layout). Note that this would have to be client-side code only, as there's no concept of history server-side (and no access to the History API on the server).

Answer (score 2):

Summary for Beginners:
As it seems on [SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto), there's no direct state communication between routes. Every option is about using a different app layer than the routes itself. The only option not mentioned by @Thomas Hennes above, is the use of store.

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, I used {replaceState: true} in my case and it works great!